# Redirect to cached page when No internet connection

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, cache-manifest

There are two pages A & B. Page A is normal Html page while Page B Html page using Cache Manifest.

**Task:** If Internet Connection is not available, Page A redirects to Page B.

**Issue:** As redirection use HTTP Request, Page B is not loaded showing *No Internet connection*

Is there any way to redirect from Page A to Page B?

Comment: History API, maybe?

Comment: @AdamAzad can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to provide a `FALLBACK` header in your manifest?

```
# Fallback content
FALLBACK:
. example.html
```

> If the (request) attempt fails, due to either a network failure or a
>   server error of some kind, the browser loads the file example.html
>   instead.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache